# Nuxeo: get all documents in their latest revisions

Tags: nuxeo

My client has a nuxeo server, which provides an API at nuxeo/webservices/relations, from which I can get all the documents. The problem is that it returns revisions, not documents. Some revisions are set to isLatestVersion = 'true', and some are set to isLatestRevision = 'false'. It is not clear to my

- how Nuxeo decides to return latest/non-latest revisions
- in which context I could possibly want to retrieve non-latest revisions of documents
- how to "force" Nuxeo to send back only documents in their latest revisions, and not the revisions themselves.

Cheers,

Albert.

Comment: What is the Nuxeo version?

Comment: Is "isLatestRevision" a typo and you wanted to write "isLatestVersion"?

Comment: When asking a question about Nuxeo, it is better to provide the output of the `nuxeoctl showconf` command, in order to precisely describe the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the "nuxeo/webservices/relations" in a recent default distribution (see http://demo.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/webservices/relations) so I'm wondering if you installed an addon?
However, I can imagine such a service would return relations. So it makes sense that the retrieved list is made of revisions since a relation can point at the non-latest revision of a document.
You are not using the right service if this is not what you want to get.

There are a lot of APIs in Nuxeo and it is possible to create custom ones, so please describe more your context: Nuxeo version, client language and wanted API. Did you look at [the REST API](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/WIvZ), [Automation](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/yYL1) and the available [WebServices/SOAP Bridge](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/GIAO)?
I would you say what you want is ask for the children of a document, see the getDocument and getChildren operations (available in all Nuxeo APIs).